# SQL Space savings indexing string column as enum

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a column called state which has the following values: `draft`, `active`, `published`, `archived`. I want to store them as a `VARCHAR` and map them to an `Enum` class.

The table may potentially have millions of rows, and I was curious about the space savings of a few methods of storing this information.

One way would be to have a `table_states` table with `id, state` columns and a `state_id` on the main table.

The other way would be to have the states stored on the main column but indexed.

Am I right in my understanding that indexed string columns internally are similarly stored to the first mentioned method?

The DB in question is MySQL but I am sure the question relates to other databases as well.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing does not make the strings take less space. In fact, it *increases* storage, because the index is a copy of the strings, in a sorted data structure.

You might like to use the MySQL [ENUM data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html):

```
ALTER TABLE WhateverYourTableNameIs
  MODIFY state ENUM('active','archived','draft','published') NOT NULL;
```

This makes the storage of the column take just 1 byte per row, because internally the strings are only part of the table definition, and they are stored on each row as an ordinal integer. You can have up to 255 enum strings in the list and it still takes 1 byte per row.

On the other hand, it requires an ALTER TABLE to redefine the ENUM list every time you want to add a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using separate table for the states and use a tinyint for the ID. The space requirement is the same as in enum (1 byte), but no limitations the enum has.